# Can I see the configuration files that spring boot creates?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I need delete spring boot from my project.how can I quickly create configuration files that spring boot did automatically?

Comment: pom.xml will have your maven project dependencies , if that is what you are refering to

Comment: Confusing, can you rephrase your question.